# TypeScript - How do you chain accessing optional nested type properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-parameter

I have a `Client` class that stores caches of other objects that the application needs to keep in memory. The structure of the object's cache is developer-defined. For example, if we have a cache of `Example` objects:

```ts
class Example {
    property1: string;
    property2: string;
}
```

The developer might only want `property1` cached.

---

```ts
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

// Constructor options for `Client`
interface ClientData {
    cacheStrategies?: CacheStrategies;
}

// How various objects should be cached
interface CacheStrategies {
    example?: ExampleCacheStrategies;
    ...
}

// Metadata for how each type of object should be cached
interface ExampleCacheStrategies {
    cacheFor?: number;
    customCache?: ExampleCustomCacheData;
}

// The custom structure of what parts of `example` objects should be cached
interface ExampleCustomCacheData {
    property1?: boolean;
    property2?: boolean;
}

// The object stored in `Client.exampleCache`, based on the custom structure defined in `ExampleCustomCacheData`
interface CustomExampleData<CachedExampleProperties extends ExampleCustomCacheData> {
    property1: CachedExampleProperties["property1"] extends true ? string /* 1 */ : undefined;
    property2: CachedExampleProperties["property2"] extends true ? string : undefined;
}

class Client<ClientOptions extends ClientData> extends EventEmitter {

    // The map's value should be based on the custom structure defined in `ExampleCustomCacheData`
    exampleCache: Map<string, CustomExampleData<ClientOptions["cacheStrategies"]["example"]["customCache"]>>;

    constructor(clientData: ClientOptions) {
        super();
        this.exampleCache = new Map();
    }
}

const client = new Client({
    cacheStrategies: {
        example: {

            /**
             * The properties of `example` objects that should be cached
             * This says that `property1` should be cached (string (1))
             */
            customCache: {
                property1: true, // (2)
                ... // (3)
            }
        }
    }
});

client.exampleCache.set("123", {
    property1: "value"
});

const exampleObject = client.exampleCache.get("123");

if (exampleObject) {

    // Should be `string` instead of `string | undefined` (2)
    console.log(exampleObject.property1);

    // `string | undefined`, as expected since it's falsey (3)
    console.log(exampleObject.property2);
}
```

As explained in the comments above the `console.log()`s, the goal is for objects that are pulled from the cache to have `property1` be a `string` instead of `string | undefined`.

The problem is that `exampleCache: Map<string, CustomExampleData<ClientOptions["cacheStrategies"]["example"]["customCache"]>>;` doesn't work since both `ClientOptions["cacheStrategies"]` and `ClientOptions["cacheStrategies"]["example"]` are optional. The following doesn't work either:

```ts
exampleCache: Map<string, CustomExampleData<ClientOptions["cacheStrategies"]?.["example"]?.["customCache"]>>;
```

It errors with `'>' expected` at `?.`. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is `"bans"` here?  Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8XlN), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (and only that issue). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz my bad, forgot to change that before posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax like [the optional chaining operator `?.`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) or the [non-null assertion operator `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) only applies to *value expressions* that will make it through to JavaScript in some form.  But you need something that works with *type expressions* which exist only in the static type system and are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when transpiled.

There is a [`NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) which is the type system analog of the non-null assertion operator.  Given a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type `T`, the type `NonNullable<T>` will be the same as `T` but without any union members of type `null` or `undefined`:

```
type Foo = string | number | undefined;
type NonNullableFoo = NonNullable<Foo>;
// type NonNullableFoo = string | number
```

In fact, the compiler actually uses it to represent the type of an expression that has the non-null assertion operator applied to it:

```
function nonNullAssertion<T>(x: T) {
    const nonNullX = x!;
    // const nonNullX: NonNullable<T>
}
```

So, everywhere you have a type `T` that includes `null` or `undefined` and you would like to remove it, you can use `NonNullable<T>`.  In your code, you will need to do it multiple times.  In the interest of something like brevity (of code, not my explanation), let's use a shorter alias:

```
type NN<T> = NonNullable<T>;
```

and then

```
class Client<C extends ClientData> extends EventEmitter {

  exampleCache: Map<string, CustomExampleData<
      NN<NN<NN<C["cacheStrategies"]>["example"]>["customCache"]>>
  >;

}
```

This compiles without error, and behaves how I think you'd like it:

```
console.log(exampleObject.property1.toUpperCase()); // string
console.log(exampleObject.property2); // undefined
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0KATgPYrpEAuAngIwCEAXNBJUQJYB2A5gNx4FiZCjQBMTFmy58cAXxwKc7VCSrY4AN3SdKsJO0qUK0WdABmpJNABE6LTojX+OAPQvoAYRKdWRAK7AlKrQZJTs3jBmwQAGHiDs2pTRSjoUZmDAmHEJOgAiYJRg2AL4wBkAFugAymwF6NwJEAD8zB4V1bVGDegQ-PKu7gASJADu0BpgHCR+MCQARgBW6IEwEOXTIAAm0HOYZcCVmylGROmZnu01RHXdMLgE0OiIqBgtcM9o6G0HHdddjX0FG5oABZdCFTYFIpRIjQdZjdAVaA0cghMwhRbLSgsdZ+LY7PbtI5cE5nTAIZCfb6VK43RrFB77SoAMVUb04fiQuyI-EZMyCSGp6DeFJeX35JEF7XyhUBA2gABVKtBgBKrL4ApQ-ERMCR0SNygVCJNKLN0dEnpSMNEMUsVjiNttdiqicc0hlyR8MB41UKZUV7oJSOQqHQ3nMSCQMGBOLyg8JQ6Jw5Ho7G5ED3ErdZjApJVOhtlxoLF4okAHSWsVC6IAGh2kALIU4yOVqtYksk-kC2swm3QZi4jaL0VFVN90qhyRJ7vOPvbSFHGH9AB4hZtF+gAArBkT0p5GTibGAbucCv1QgB8DPjIZotFaRI324TYR6AG1rEJb3RrABdR7wAeR7Iv4mBNJ20jQC4ABU0C0NA0HuMwfiHv2g6bHG+BfiI1CiA+Pzrl6W47lQjQfthiZ-gBQEwGwfhgRBPDQMhqEDpwBZyiimCsiQ0AALyMdw0AAD7QByXLGKJKF9mxHE4Fx0AAHLeIpeLgHMGA8fxSkqWpYAaegy48Re-DAgpymcKpIDqZpkbab4kGieJ3IKGYKGBOEzacLp1kAIJQLu3jLgqF4ABTwMwCoAJTXqUETYt5llqQAGtp8D0JhUHuMA8ViT5IDJcwFlWTZhkhem8nUKiimKcFV4CcVekGXVCgKbk6DoCgABK6AAI5+OwOqbHV2lYNAb4ANLQEWADW6DUHqiq-gAtG87WdT1-WDQWwWTb+V79KAkAwNkiSrtR2jAadeSXhdh7HvYuj6IYxi4CUWWKsqSBgCgADkMATCA9EOniTqYHMDbbN4LZ7Gqnaaj20Ayeh03NiORGnpK56FMkDyVlS7TMCCP3Lg5PB1pjC5ESu70PDVy70-THgfkyvx0j0f4Xh++MYJzLPjj8nMXu9JkKIy8VdkERChaAOSUP6rQxYGDz4BAfghqFUWZQ8lDlOwEAVhj7TaexYzEygmuZf0h25bLiQm+gYzXZQoXKy6Py0v8PTMG7eNET7Ysq0HMHQbTQf4LBWaECRr5msWPPoDa8x2qaLZGmsjoEu7hxh+Hkd66sYDULRhrYtEFF3jaGeg1nrPbKFZNCaFtBRVFudB4h7d8vOQoB+H-fRy+dDMHR6B1sCoWiG3A8EPI-dz7Pchawods6IbVpfO0ZYQOCoXWLQogAMzWHWbsV8PNiA-RJ-vefeHQNJaHsUcsjLzgOU+NiCcAPI5tiAmr0oOvKsW9uC733kfawb92DolCj-P+St3ofwgFGdAZYQAkG4HAoiv8U5lnPrQMsQQACqKAQxtB3prLWH1G5IIiKg9BmDsEb1wVifBMdcLUOBI-WSL8cBAA)